# Inner padding for column layout?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple page that flows the content into columns. Is there a way to apply an inner padding per column? I see the column-gap property, but that doesn't work for the left side of the first column I believe. Also I need my columns to be exactly 300px wide. This is my setup:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <style>
    .columns {
      column-width: 300px;
    }
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="columns">  
      ...
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Ideally there would be some property like:

```
column-inner-padding: ...;
```

I can kind of get this to work by explicitly setting a padding on all elements within the columns, but that does not scale well:

```
.columnsParagraph {
   padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
}

...

<div class="columns">  
  <p class="columnsParagraph">...</p>
  <p class="columnsParagraph">...</p>
  <p class="columnsParagraph">...</p>
  ...
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: If I understand you right you want to set the padding of every element inside your columns class, something like this should work `.columns > * { padding: 5px}`

Comment: Hi Shriike, yes that's right, but I am unfamiliar with that styling syntax, could you please write out a full example of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a class change the styles of elements under that element the class is applied to.
[Star Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)

This would apply the style to every element anywhere downstream from an element with the columns class.

```
.columns *
```

This would apply the style to every direct descendant element from your element that has the columns class.

```
.columns > *
```

You could also replace * with any other selector, for example p to apply to all of your p tags underneath columns.

Answer (score -1):

try this in css:

```
.columnsParagraph{
    padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: The OP was trying to set padding for element underneath the columns class, not set padding for columns itself.